# How do I transform a set of vertices into a hexagon shape

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, geometry, vertex-groups

I'm new to Blender and I've been trying to attempt to create a low-poly character and I came across this speed build video where one was able to instantly transform a set of vertices into a  hexagon shape so they can make the arm. Does anyone know how to do that like in the gif below? What are the hotkeys used for doing so?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Most likely he used the "Loop Tools" standard addon which can be activated in the preferences.

[image]

It is accessible use the <kbd>W</kbd> key or in the right tabs, in the "Edit" part:

[image]

Comment: It's also on the right-click popup menu so no need to use 'W' or the N panel. (This assumes that you have Blender set to use left-click select of course.)

Comment: left click select... unholy thing ; ) ... @JohnEason

Comment: Most recent users who never saw or used 2.79 and earlier have never used anything else so one has to cater for them nowadays! :^))